# Sql supreme optimization

Tags: mysql, join

i have an very akward sql query which i can not figure how to optimize it even more than it is.

```
SELECT dc.main_photo,d.trending, dc.reviews_num, dc.thumb_updated, dc.avg_overall_rating AS overall_rating, dc.photos_num, d.id, d.name, d.showname, d.blur_rating, d.approved, d.address, d.pref_contact_option, d.phone, d.phone2, d.website,d.flag_nofake, d.website2, d.website3, d.website4, d.tattoos, d.smokes, d.tranny, d.lat, d.lng, d.moved_to_id, d.admin_notes, d.closed, d.verified_by_admin, ci.city_name, ci.city_id, co.country_id, co.country_name, co.country_iso, IF (dc.photos_num > 0 , 1, 0) AS has_photo,eth.ethnicity_name as ethnicity, prop.prop_value as age,
r.updated_at as newest_review_date, d.bkp_last_online, d.featured 
FROM dancers d 
INNER JOIN dancers_counters dc ON d.id = dc.dancer_id
LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.id = dc.last_review_id
INNER JOIN countries co ON co.country_id = d.country_id
LEFT JOIN cities ci ON ci.city_id = d.city_id
left join ethnicities eth on eth.ethnicity_id = d.ethnicity 
left join all_properties prop on prop.id = d.age 
WHERE  d.approved=1 AND d.moved_to_id = 0 AND d.country_id=44
ORDER BY  d.featured DESC , d.closed ASC, has_photo DESC, d.trending DESC, newest_review_date DESC 
LIMIT 19965, 15
```

Problem is this query takes

```
 Showing rows 19965 - 19979 (15 total, Query took 0.4739 seconds.) [featured: 0 - 0] [closed: 0 - 0] [trending: 0 - 0]
```

aproximatelly 0.5 seconds which is a lot considering that this query can be called for a lot of times in the page, for each user.
Tried to explain the query and i have this: http://prntscr.com/gocfb3 ( sorry i can not attach).
Is there anyway that i can optimize it even more ? or this is the max that i can get from this query?

P.S Tried with an sub-select, getting all the dancers which are into the "where" clause but that only got me into an more increase in time spent for the query.

Comment: Can't you ads cache layer?

Comment: RIght now i am using memcache for an cache system, and i cache every query, problem that i have is when the query is not cached and in the second there are more users that try to get into the site then this query takes a loong looong time. The logic what i am using , whenever i try to query something, i first verify if it is in memcache , if it is there, i retrieve it from there, if not , i query and put it into memcache for 1h.

Comment: check this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-queries-and-tables-in-mysql-and-mariadb-on-a-vps && http://www.techfounder.net/2011/03/25/database-optimization-techniques-you-can-actually-use/

Comment: Thank you for the links chirag but i have done everything that it is to be done for my "sql experience" which isn't that vast, cache, indexing,as mysql engine is InnoDB, picked up only needed columns but still didn't managed to surpass the time spent for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Set Composite Indexes on: 
**d.approved,d.moved_to_id,d.country_id,d.city_id,d.ethnicity,d.age**

And: 
**d.approved,d.moved_to_id,d.country_id**

And:
**d.city_id,d.ethnicity,d.age**

And: 
**dc.dancer_id,dc.last_review_id**

Then try to re-test the query with Explain to see which Index the MySQL optimizer chooses.

The ORDER BY & LIMIT statement is what's causing the query to be slow since MySQL needs to sort and scan the full table first before returning the limited rows. Since you are sorting on columns coming from multiple tables, the MySQL optimizer will have no choice but to do a filesort rather than sort on any of your indexes. If possible sort through columns coming from one table only (`dancer` table) and add a composite index on those columns.

Comment: Hi, right now , with those indexes added, the query is 0.5023 seconds, did one test and removed from the sort the 2 columns which weren't from d. table and it went as timestamp from 0.5 to 0.2990.